How to align image size with node size
I want to display a colored box below an image in a tikzpicture within a beamer presentation. But I am failing to align the sizes correctly, possibly due to the node border.
But adjusting the border size or removing the border does not have the expected effect, and the box still does not match the width of the image. The issue seems to only present on the right border.
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
    \node (image) at (0.5\paperwidth,0.5\paperheight) {\includegraphics[width=0.7\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-plain}};
    \node[rectangle,
    draw=green,
    fill=green,
    ultra thin,
    minimum width=0.7\paperwidth,
    minimum height=0.3\paperheight] (titlebox) at (0.5\paperwidth,0.25\paperheight) {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}




Can you reproduce the problem with one of the test images form the mwe package? This way we could compile your code.

Are you sure the black line isn't part of the image?

If I test your code with another image I get https://i.sstatic.net/IU9Ex3Wk.png in which the image and node seems to be aligned.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - yes as it protrudes about one pixel to the right as soon as I use a border, and it is tool small if I do not use a border. I adapted the example to use a green box instead of a black one to highlight the issue.

Looks fine for me: https://i.sstatic.net/65YWS66B.png Please edit your question so we can actually compile your code, by either using an example image from your tex distribution or by proving the image.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I adjusted the example to use the mwe package. The issue only seems to occur if I go into presenter mode using F5

In this case it might be an issue with your pdfviewer.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - yes you are right. I tried both evolution and Okular and both exhibited the issue, which is why I thought it is tikz related. However, Firefox does not have the single pixel issue. You are welcome to add this as the answer and I will accept it. Thank you for your help.

As can be seen from this code:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\includegraphics[width=10cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image}};
\node[
line width=20pt,
draw=red,
fill=green,
minimum width=10cm,
minimum height=3cm,
] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


A node of minimum width=10cm will naturally be drawn with half the line width sticking out on both sides.
To prevent this simply do not draw the border(the default behaviour) - do not add draw or draw=.... If the draw is set elsewhere, you can use draw=none.
